# PyQt5: QGraphicsItem multiple inheritance

Tags: pyqt, qgraphicsitem

I am overwriting an item that can be either rectangle or circle (share the same functions, properties). I'd like to have one class that is inherited from both shape as followed:

```
class Pad(QGraphicsRectItem, QGraphicsEllipseItem):
def __init__(self, pos, isCircle=False, parent=None):
    w, h = 200, 100 
    if isCircle:
        QGraphicsEllipseItem.__init__(self, -w/2, -h/2, w, h)  
    else:
        QGraphicsRectItem.__init__(self, -w/2, -h/2, w, h)
```

This results with the only shape of the first parent (`QGraphicsRectItem` in this case). Could someone explain why and provide suggestion?

Full code below:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class Pad(QGraphicsRectItem, QGraphicsEllipseItem):
    def __init__(self, pos, isCircle=False, parent=None):
        w, h = 200, 100 
        if isCircle:
            QGraphicsEllipseItem.__init__(self, -w/2, -h/2, w, h)  
        else:
            QGraphicsRectItem.__init__(self, -w/2, -h/2, w, h)  
        self.setPos(pos)
        self.parent = parent
        self.color = QColor(255, 0, 0)
        self.setPen(QPen(self.color, Qt.MiterJoin, 1))
        self.setBrush(QBrush(self.color))

def main():
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    scene = QGraphicsScene()

    rect = Pad(QPointF(0, 0), False, scene)
    circle = Pad(QPointF(300, 300), True, scene)
    scene.addItem(rect)
    scene.addItem(circle)
    
    view = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView(scene)
    view.setRenderHints(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing)
    view.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### TL;DR

Use a QGraphicsPathItem.

### Explanation

The order of the base classes decides the final behavior of *all* methods: it's called *method resolution order* (MRO). The fact that you called the `__init__` of a different class is completely irrelevant.

Consider the following:

```py
class Rectangle:
    def paint(self):
        print('draw rectangle')

class Circle:
    def paint(self):
        print('draw circle')

class Test1(Rectangle, Circle):
    def __init__(self):
        Rectangle.__init__(self)

class Test2(Circle, Rectangle):
    def __init__(self):
        # note that we're still calling the __init__ of the Rectangle class
        Rectangle.__init__(self)


>>> Test1().paint()
'draw rectangle'
>>> Test2().paint()
'draw circle'
```

This is because any override of any inherited base class will take precedence, based on the [reverse] *order* of inheritance: the method that will be actually called will be the *first* override in the MRO.

While, under certain aspects, the QGraphicsRectItem and QGraphicsEllipseItem classes are *very* similar, you must also *always* remember that PyQt (and PySide) are *bindings*: their behavior not only depends on the python class, but also on their wrapped C++ objects.

That's why it's usually impossible to use multiple inheritance of C++ derived classes<sup>[1]</sup>.

If those classes were *pure* python, the solution would be quite easy: considering what explained above, the paint method should also call the method of the correct class:

```py
class Pad(QGraphicsRectItem, QGraphicsEllipseItem):
    def __init__(self, pos, isCircle=False, parent=None):
        # ...
        self.isCircle = isCircle

    def paint(self, painter, option, widget=None):
        if self.isCircle:
            QGraphicsEllipseItem.paint(self, painter, option, widget)
        else:
            QGraphicsRectItem.paint(self, painter, option, widget)
```

Unfortunately, this is not the case for *wrapped* methods of bound C++ objects, as they internally access memory addresses for their properties, and you will most certainly get some unexpected behavior. If you're lucky, you'll only have strange graphical results. Worst case scenarios include the program freezing or even crash.

For instance, try adding the following line in the `if isCircle:` block of the init:

```py
            print(self.startAngle(), self.spanAngle())
```

Running the above gives unexpected (and unpredictable) results, like `97 -1220601744` or `105 -1220401040`. Adding the same line in `paint` also gives a completely different result than what was printed in the init.

The solution is quite simple: don't try to use multiple inheritance, but use a better class as [QGraphicsPathItem](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicspathitem.html):

```py
class Pad(QGraphicsPathItem):
    def __init__(self, pos, isCircle=False, parent=None):
        w, h = 200, 100 
        rect = QRectF(-w/2, -h/2, w, h)
        path = QPainterPath()
        if isCircle:
            path.addEllipse(rect)
        else:
            path.addRect(rect)
        super().__init__(path, parent)
        self.setPos(pos)
        self.parent = parent
        self.color = QColor(255, 0, 0)
        self.setPen(QPen(self.color, Qt.MiterJoin, 1))
        self.setBrush(QBrush(self.color))
```

<sup>Note: the `parent` argument of a QGraphicsItem must *always* be a QGraphicsItem based class; if you intend to directly provide the scene for some reason, use a specific positional or keyworded argument (in your code you didn't use the `parent` argument in the class, but you provided it anyway, and it was of the wrong type); also consider that if you're trying to do that so that the item adds itself to the scene, that's generally not considered good practice, unless you *really* know what you're doing.</sup>

Comment: Thank you for providing clear explanation. The solution works perfectly. Also, thanks for pointing out my bad practice in the _note_ section. I will have them corrected.